# Set Hue of Value Counts of Categores with a Numeric Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have plotted out the value-counts of categories of a column in a bar plot - and now I want each category to be colored according to the average value of a numeric column for that category.

I also want a line plot showing the trend of the change in the average of the numeric column accross different categories. So far, I've done this:

```
mask = lambda x: x>=50
n_mask = lambda x: x<50
true_mask = df['CatCol'].value_counts().loc[mask]
false_mask = df['CatCol'].value_counts().loc[n_mask].sum()
cols = true_mask
cols['Other Categories occuring less than 50 times'] = false_mask
cols.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.7, figsize=(12,12))
```